# Selecting Content in quotes using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

If I have:

```
    ["eaacbf7e-37b3-509e-b2d1-ddce7f0e1f6e", "f9e52e06-697a-57af-9566-d05fabb001a4", 
     "19edb822-eccb-5289-8fee-a39cdda66cd5", "83d3ad63-b468-5a1e-ba6c-6b69eb4a3dc5"]
```

(where the entire thing is a string)

Is there a simple regular expression that I can use to select content within the quotes (quotes included)?

Since the above comes out as a string. I want to use regex to select out each id within the quotes (along with the quotes) and store them into a ruby array.

Comment: Why are you getting the string in that format? It almost looks like JSON output, which, if it is, should be parsed by the JSON module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use this regex

`"[^"]*"`

`[^"]*` says match any character  except `"` i.e `[^"]` 0 to many times i.e `*`

Comment: Oh my goodness ... had a feeling it was something that simple. Extremely new at this, lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`String#scan` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) with the regular expression `/"[^"]+"/`:

```ruby
ids = str.scan(/"[^"]+"/) # => [ "eaacbf7e-...", "f9e52e06-...", ...]
puts ids
"eaacbf7e-37b3-509e-b2d1-ddce7f0e1f6e"
"f9e52e06-697a-57af-9566-d05fabb001a4"
"19edb822-eccb-5289-8fee-a39cdda66cd5"
"83d3ad63-b468-5a1e-ba6c-6b69eb4a3dc5"
```

That expression breaks down like so:

```ruby
str.scan(/"[^"]+"/)
#         │├──┘│└─ Another literal quotation mark (").
#         ││   └─ Match one or more of the previous thing.
#         │└─ A class matching any character except (^) quotation marks.
#         └─ A literal quotation mark (").
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you getting the string in that format? It looks like JSON output, which, if it is, should be parsed by the JSON module.

```
require 'json'
require 'pp'

foo = [
  "eaacbf7e-37b3-509e-b2d1-ddce7f0e1f6e",
  "f9e52e06-697a-57af-9566-d05fabb001a4",
  "19edb822-eccb-5289-8fee-a39cdda66cd5",
  "83d3ad63-b468-5a1e-ba6c-6b69eb4a3dc5"
]

foo.to_json
=> "[\"eaacbf7e-37b3-509e-b2d1-ddce7f0e1f6e\",\"f9e52e06-697a-57af-9566-d05fabb001a4\",\"19edb822-eccb-5289-8fee-a39cdda66cd5\",\"83d3ad63-b468-5a1e-ba6c-6b69eb4a3dc5\"]"
```

That's probably the string you're getting. If you parse it using the JSON parser, you'll get back a Ruby array:

```
pp JSON[ foo.to_json ]
=> ["eaacbf7e-37b3-509e-b2d1-ddce7f0e1f6e",
"f9e52e06-697a-57af-9566-d05fabb001a4",
"19edb822-eccb-5289-8fee-a39cdda66cd5",
"83d3ad63-b468-5a1e-ba6c-6b69eb4a3dc5"]
```